# Service is started via BroadcastReceiver "randomly"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-notifications

I want to have an Notification on an specified Time each day.

For that I implemented an Broadcast receiver and an AlarmManager.

My doubt is that the receiver is reacting to every broadcast of the system.

Cause if I setup the alarmManager it is working fine for a while but than I got an notification nearly every hour (approximately).

And an other strange behaviour, if i go in airplane mode, the notifications doesn't show up.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
   Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
   context.startService(service1);
  }  
}
```

in the main activity

```
    long REPEATE_TIME_MS=86400000 /*24h*/;      
/* notification handling */
    String syncConnPref = this.sharedPref.getString("notificationTime", "12:00"); 
    String[] pieces=syncConnPref.split(":");
    /* setup the start time for the alarm */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long nowInMillisecs = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(pieces[0], 10));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(pieces[1], 10));
    long alarmStartTimeUnMillisecs = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if(alarmStartTimeUnMillisecs<=nowInMillisecs)
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        alarmStartTimeUnMillisecs = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.notificationContext, MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.notificationContext, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.notificationContext.getSystemService(Service.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), REPEATE_TIME_MS, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm setup with :"+ calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+ calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

manifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.whoseturn.MyReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this, or workaround?